# How to skip <a> tag while scraping data using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

HTML:

```
<tbody>
       <tr >
           <td> Tim Cook </td>
           <td class="wpsTableNrmRow" > Apple CEO
               <a href:applicatiodetailaddress> all CEOs </a> // Nor required this node
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr >
           <td> Sundar Pichai </td>
           <td class="wpsTableNrmRow" > Google CEO </td>
       </tr>
       <tr >
           <td> NoCompany </td>
           <td class="wpsTableNrmRow" > NOT, DEFINED</td>
       </tr>
</tbody>
```

Code:

```
applicationData = [td.text for td in webBrowser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="wpsTableNrmRow"]')]
record = {'Designation': applicationData[0],
 'Designation': applicationData[1],'Designation': applicationData[2]}
```

OUTPUT:

```
 Designation: Apple CEO all CEOs  // Not required 'all CEOs'
 Designation: Google CEO
 Designation: Not, DEFINED
```

I am scraping data from the table and the <a tag is also scraped. I don't want to scrape <a tag.

How can I do this?

I tried `[td.get_attribute("textContent").split("\n")[0] for td in webBrowser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="wpsTableNrmRow" and text()!=" "]')]`

OUTPUT:

```
 Designation: Apple CEO  
 Designation: Google CEO
 Designation:           // should have value 'NOT, DEFINED'
```

How to get value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
applicationData = [td.get_attribute("textContent").split("\n")[0] for td in webBrowser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="wpsTableNrmRow"]')]
record = {'Designation1': applicationData[0], 'Designation2': applicationData[1]}
```

**Try above code , here we use TextCOntent and it returns different text nodes in different lines so you can split it using "\n"**

Comment: <td class="wpsTableNrmRow" >  </td>

Comment: How to skip empty text nodes?

Comment: Could you ask as a separate question with example html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66304166/skip-empty-text-nodes-using-selenium-in-python

Comment: Your sol is not printing NOT, DEFINED values. I updated the code. Have a look and support me.