# skip empty text nodes using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

HTML:

```
<tbody>
       <tr >
           <td> Type1 </td>
           <td class="wpsTableNrmRow" > This is Node1
               <a href:applicatiodetailaddress> all Nodes </a>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr >
           <td> Type2 </td>
           <td class="wpsTableNrmRow" > This is Node2 </td>
       </tr>
       <tr >
           <td> Type3 </td>
           <td class="wpsTableNrmRow" > </td>
       </tr>
</tbody>
```

Code:

```
applicationData = [td.get_attribute("textContent").split("\n")[0] for td in webBrowser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="wpsTableNrmRow"]')]
print(applicationData)
```

OUTPUT:

```
 ["This is Node1", "This is Node2", ""]
```

I am scraping data from the table and the empty text is also scraped. I don't want to scrape empty text.

I tried `('//td[normalize-space(@class="wpsTableNrmRow")]')`,  `('//td[@class="wpsTableNrmRow"]')/*normalize-space()` and `(//td[@class="wpsTableNrmRow"]/*[.!=''])`  but not working.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can use loctor to ensure text is not empty:**

```
//td[@class="wpsTableNrmRow" and text()!=" "]
```

**So use:**

```
applicationData = [td.get_attribute("textContent").split("\n")[
    0] for td in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="wpsTableNrmRow" and text()!=" " and text()!=""]')]
print(applicationData)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66292406/how-to-skip-a-tag-while-scraping-data-using-selenium/66295902?noredirect=1#comment117216375_66295902

Comment: did you try the answer ? please accept the answer if it helped

Comment: @user15069057 the comment on previous answer was for this or the other one . Please comment only one respective threads .

Comment: Link is for other one.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply conditional to [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which will apply the function to the variable if the variable pass the condition(s).

Like this:

```
[f(x) for x in sequence if condition]
```

Applied to your code:

```
applicationData = [td.get_attribute("textContent").split("\n")[0] for td in webBrowser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="wpsTableNrmRow"]') if td.get_attribute("textContent").strip() == ""]
print(applicationData)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66292406/how-to-skip-a-tag-while-scraping-data-using-selenium/66295902?noredirect=1#comment117216375_66295902

Answer (score 0):

The `translate` function looks like it might work fine to solve your issue:

```
applicationData = [td.get_attribute("textContent").split("\n")[0] for td in webBrowser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="wpsTableNrmRow" and translate(text(), " ", "")]')]
print(applicationData)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66292406/how-to-skip-a-tag-while-scraping-data-using-selenium/66295902?noredirect=1#comment117216375_66295902